# Hopscotch.js, dynamically created modal target not functioning

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm using linkedIn's Hopscotch.

I want to show a bubble to a modal popup, but hopscotch seems to skip the step width the modal.

My guess is the problem is related to the hopscotch target not being there when the tour object is initialized, as the modal is shown on "onNext"-event of a tour step. I've tried both giving the actual object and id-selector as "target"-attribute. I couldn't get either to work.

One extreme option could be to make two different tours, and on the onEnd event of the first one to show the modal, wait until the modal rendering is finished, and then show the "next" tour. But before resorting to this kind of weirdness I'd like to find a neat solution.

Comment: any solution till now? To get it work, I am writing hacky code which I really hate.

Comment: Not really. I just ended up omitting some of the instructions for now. Some ideas for a not-so-ugly-hack could be to display the elements before tour start, but to position them absolutely & out of the screen, and move them into the screen on the "onNext".. I'm not sure if this works, but just came to my mind.  Other ones would be to manipulate hopscotch internals to allow changing the target element (or its positioning) there on the "onNext" event...

Comment: Did anyone solved it?

Comment: @NehaChoudhary did you wrote hack for it???

Comment: @Marcus how did you solved it finally?

Comment: @sarsarahman dint complete it.

Comment: @NehaChoudhary finally i just used the header bar as target and just manipulated the positions to solve it for now. if you find any solution in future please inform me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue, so i added a method to refresh the next step target element:

```
/**
 * getCurrTarget
 *
 * @return {Object} The currently visible target.
 */
 {some code...}


 /**
 * setNextTarget   
 * @ Refresh the target dom element for the next step
 */
 this.setNextTarget = function(el) {
  currTour.steps[currStepNum+1].target = el;
 };
```

And then i use it like this:

```
 {step 1 code...}
 onShow:function(){
   hopscotch.setNextTarget($("#myStep2Target")[0]);                         
 }
```

Not the best approach, but fast to go... hope it helps ;)

Comment: Yeah, I guess there's no good solution at the moment. For single page apps this can be a bit of a pain...

Answer (score 1):

To get hopscotch to resolve dynamic targets every time you run a tour, you can simply clone the tour definition i.e.

```
hopscotch.startTour($.extend(true, {}, tour));
```

Comment: The problem was related to dynamic elements that should be made visible in the middle of the tour. So at the moment of starting the tour, they are not necessarily in the DOM (-> re-starting doesn't change the situation).

Comment: @Marcus I sort of guessed that after posting, but hopefully the cloning approach is useful for other people (like me) doing single-page apps.

NB I've submitted a pull request to resolve the target dynamically at every step https://github.com/linkedin/hopscotch/pull/91